# I need custom range on slider, like 1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20,25..... Do we achieve this?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need range slider having 1 to 5 without a gap and after 5 digits of a gap between each no. Like 1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20,25,30.....70

```
<rzslider rz-slider-model="slider.value" rz-slider-options="slider.options"></rzslider>

$scope.slider = {
  value: 100,
  options: {
    floor: 0,
    ceil: 500,
    step: 1,
  }
};
```

I tried above code as well but it gives series like 1,5,10,15,20,25..70 but I need this series like 1,2,3,4,5,10,15,20,25,....70

[image]

appreciate if anyone helps me with that. 
thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the pattern that you're trying to work with?

Comment: Where do want this series. In `$scope.slider` or `$scope.slider.options` ?

Comment: IN short, I want range as above in image I have attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `stepsArray` in options as,

```
options: {
    stepsArray: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The slider is simple mechanic, it slides from X to X with X interval.
Almost every time a different scale is accomplished, it is done by some function calculating the value you want afterwards by giving it the slider value as input.

```
input => output:
1 => 1
2 => 2
 ...
6 => 10
7 => 15
```